# Hard to Pin-Point High Temp Limit Switch Issue

Tags: hvac

I have been having an issue with my furnace for awhile now which can't seem to be solved. Had a furnace service out to review it and he spent 6 hours here trying everything. Below are the facts. Hopefully someone here will be able to help!

1. Have a carrier high-efficiency 80k BTU 93% furnace
2. Model # is 59SC5A080S171216 and Serial # is 2316A58989
3. Was manufactured June 2016. I need to look back at our receipts but believe it was installed late 2016 / early 2017.
4. Installed a Honeywell RTH9585WF1004 Wi-Fi Smart Thermostat about a year and a half ago
5. Home is 1666 sq ft in the metro Detroit area with a finished basement
6. Home has always maintained temperature hot or cold, all vents blow warm/cold air when requested

Now for the issue. I noticed a power cycle of my new thermostat which happened every 10-15 minutes while it ran. I did a lot of googling and it seemed that it was the high-temp limit switch tripping. I had a highly recommended heat and cooling service provider come out and below is the list of everything he looked at and tried.

1. Saw the high-limit switch was tripping which was causing the power to be cut to the smart thermostat
2. Replaced the high-limit with no fix to the issue
3. Took out the filter (16x25x5 3M filter) and still tripped
4. Even with the filter out, the filter door open, and even the control panel door open, the limit switch still tripped
5. All vents (return and feed) are completely open with nothing blocking them
6. All dampers are completely open
7. The furnace fan was turned up to a higher speed and still tripped
8. Everything is clean
9. AC coils were checked for dirt and are spotless
10. Ducting was measured for being undersized and are not

He finally tested the pressure before/after the furnace and it seemed that the feed into the furnace was not enough. I do not have those pressure numbers but am re-measuring them soon. The suggestion was to add a 12x6 vent right before the filter to attempt to allow more air into the system. Unfortunately, even adding this 12x6 vent AND removing the filter, it STILL trips the limit switch which is killing power to the thermostat.

Basically myself and the technician are out of all ideas and have no idea what the issue is. Anyone on here that has ANY idea would be greatly apricated.

Comment: #11. Cleaned the flame sensor. #12. Bypassed the t-stat. #13. Verified incoming power and gas. #14. Replaced the entire safety chain. #15. Replaced gas valve. #16. Replaced transformer. #17. Replaced board. - That's "everything".

Comment: Power cycle with new thermostat, start over at what changed. Go back and see if the problem is the new thermostat. It s rare but some models pull down the transformer and that can cause all kinds of problems. I have only seen this 1 time but have friends that have seen it multiple times.